# Javascript select content which is inside the tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a problem selecting the content inside a tag.
Here is the example:

```
<li>aaaa</li>
<li>bbbb</li>
<li>cccc</li>
```

I want to select the `aaaa bbbb cccc` and store them in an array. 
If I use `document.getElementsByTagName`, it will store the `<li></li>`tags as well. How can I just pick the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and return just text of each `li` with `textContent`

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var result = Array.from(li).map(function(e) {
  return e.textContent;
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>bbbb</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the elements and get the text content

```
let textArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('li')).map(function(elem) {
    return elem.textContent;
});

console.log(textArray); // ["aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"]
```

Using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` grabs just the text without any tags that may exists with the `li` elements